# Simplifying Exponentials (Fourier)

Tags: exponential-function, roots-of-unity

I am having trouble simplifying the following expression:

$$
\frac{1}{7}\left(1+e^{-jk\frac{2\pi}{7}}+e^{-jk\frac{4\pi}{7}}+e^{-jk\frac{6\pi}{7}}+e^{-jk\frac{8\pi}{7}}\right)
$$

I need to get 
$$
\frac{1}{7 \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{7}\right)}\left(e^{-jk\frac{4\pi}{7}}\sin\left(\frac{5\pi k}{7}\right)\right)
$$

Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What is $j$ is it $j^2=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

We sum the geometric progression of $e^{-i2\pi/7}$ to find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac17\sum_{k=0}^4 \left(e^{-i2\pi/7}\right)^k&=\frac17\frac{1-e^{-i10\pi/7}}{1-e^{-i2\pi/7}}\\\\
&=\frac17\frac{e^{-i5\pi/7}(e^{i5\pi/7}-e^{-i5\pi/7})}{e^{-i\pi/7}(e^{i\pi/7}-e^{-i\pi/7})}\\\\
&=\frac17e^{-i4\pi/7}\frac{\sin(5\pi/7)}{\sin(\pi/7)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark